# how to find the vcruntime140.dll in flutter build windows?

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

I am new to Flutter, I've tried to build a Windows application right now. But in Flutter docs, they said that I have to put these files in my `build` folder. Where I can find those files so I can build my Flutter to a .exe program?

This showed an error while I transfer it folder to my friend's computer.

[image]

Comment: you need to copy the files from the installation directory of your ``Visual C++ Redistributable For Visual Studio`` program directory.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/redistributing-visual-cpp-files?view=msvc-170

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To resolve the issue of missing DLL files (`msvcp140.dll`, `vcruntime140.dll`, `vcruntime140_1.dll`), here is how to do it:

1. Locating the missing files:

   - **Scenario 1 64-bit PC with 64-bit Flutter Build or 32-bit PC with 32-bit Flutter Build:** Open `C:\Windows\System32`.
   - **Scenario 2 64-bit PC with 32-bit Flutter Build:** Open `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`.
2. Locate the following files: `msvcp140.dll`, `vcruntime140.dll`, `vcruntime140_1.dll`.
3. Copy these files and paste them into `build/windows/runner/Release` directory in your Flutter project.